# What was the first anime/manga/light novel to accurately represent Japanese school life?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history, light-novel-history

A common theme in a number of anime/manga/light novels is that the cast are students currently going to school. While some titles use this as a backdrop to show how the cast used to have normal lives before they made to fight in conflicts against aliens/monsters/gods/the military, there are some which just show the cast's daily life in school.

I am wondering: what were the first anime, manga and light novel to accurately represent Japanese school life? Did they ever get any adaptations?

Comment: How strict are you going to be with "accurately"? I imagine that most school-themed series are going to have some basis in truth, but for the sake of the work I can't imagine any adaptation being entirely accurate.

Comment: Whaaat ? You mean it's not mandatory for every japanese schoolboys to have harem ?

Comment: @Makoto well when i said accurately i wanted to filter out any titles where it depicts school life but some of the events are unreal like supernatual encounters. the only examples i can think of which i would call accurate (from my limited understanding) is Toradora, Kimi ni Todoke and Maria Watches Over Us

Comment: Oh, so you're looking more for the slice of life aspect of it as opposed to anything else, right?  It doesn't seem like you're interested in pure vanilla since both Toradora and Kimi ni Todoke had extenuating circumstances attached with both of them, but that does make for a decent basis, at least.

Comment: @Makoto well i am interested in a pure vanilla example however i don't know what pure vanilla school life would look like. i thought the ones i named were good examples of Japanese school life with some liberates in them

Comment: Let me quantify then.  Toradora has a unique circumstance in which the protagonist and deuteragonist meet, and some of their plot-critical interactions would likely not be what you'd find in real life.  Kimi ni Todoke is likely closer to what you're looking for in terms of plot-driven circumstance, so I'll keep my feelers out for any information along those lines.

Comment: Bit late but what I found during researching for [my answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/63920/do-japanese-student-councils-have-actual-power-punishing-students-revoking-clu/63921), I concluded that "Only Yesterday(1991)" and "His and Her Circumstaces(1998-99)" were some anime which portrayed student council accurately. Some recent shows like "The silent voice", "K-On", "Re-Life"([here](https://manga.tokyo/otaku-articles/anime-realistic-japanese-high-school-students)), "GTO", "Dragon Sakura"([here](https://freeaddon.com/anime-vs-real-life-school/)) did some accurate portrayal.

Comment: Also, see this reddit posts for more information: https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/augkal/an_anime_thats_accurate_to_actual_japan_life/

Answer (score 1):

As far as anime go, how about...

**The Kabocha Wine** (1982)

Not sure if this is accurate enough for you, but it's the first anime about school life that doesn't involve aliens or stuff along those lines that I can think of.